# Storage size of SDL_Thread isn’t known?

Tags: c, multithreading, sdl, sdl-2

When I try to compile this:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include "SDL_thread.h"
int main(void) {    
    SDL_Thread athread; 
    return 0;
}
```

with:

```
gcc SDL_Thread_test.c -o SDL_Thread_test `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL
```

I get:

```
error: storage size of ‘athread’ isn’t known
  SDL_Thread athread;
             ^
```

Perhaps there is something else I need to #include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a SDL_thread structure. The structure information is private and not known to the compiler.

SDL_Thread API only requires you to use a pointer to SDL_Thread which you can declare.

```
SDL_Thread* thread ;    //note the pointer
thread = SDL_CreateThread(int (*fn)(void *), void *data);
```

You will never need to operate with a structure directly.